# iPhone device test Issue

Tags: iphone

i wanted test my app on iPhone , i have added  TestMyDevelProfile to provisioning of my iPhone and added to my pbxproj , still am getting this code sign error.

Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'TestMyDevelProfile 'can't be found

Comment: It's iPhone, not I-phone. I know google is pretty good with spelling errors like that these days but it's still a good idea to spell things correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you say, you have added to project?

And, do you see them in `Project Settings -> Build -> Code Signing identity`?